# CheckBox on ReadyToInstall Dialog in Basic MSI in Installshield

Tags: windows-installer, installshield-2010

I have two product Configuration releases for my MSI, namely Release1 & Release2.
I have added a checkbox to the ReadyToInstall Dialog. I want this checkbox to be visible only when I build Release2. Running an Installer from Release1 should display the usual ReaddyToInstall Dialog Box without showing any CheckBox.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is your name by chance Himanshu?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by adding a release flag to your releases and a condition (see the Conditions tab in the lower right when you're on the dialog's Behavior node) to hide or show the checkbox if [ISReleaseFlags](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q106453) does or does not contain the appropriate flags. You can check contains with the >< operator, per [Conditional Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#substring_operators).